# How to call method inside xml file

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml

I'm working on a .NET project that uses a XML provider to connect the application to the database.
In my XML file I have the following connectionString:

```
<connectionString>Server=XXX;Database=XXX;UID=XXX;PWD=XXX</connectionString>
```

At the moment the password I provide is hardly coded, but what I need to do is to call inside the XML a method (from a project in the solution) that returns the password.

Is it possible to use inside the XML c# code to call the method? what others solutions could I consider?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "call inside the XML"? xml is a string, that you parse and get values, not an executable.  You can read the xml and get values and attributes and then use that value

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml = "<doc><connectionString>Server=XXX;Database=XXX;UID=XXX;PWD=XXX</connectionString></doc>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            XElement connectionString = doc.Descendants("connectionString").FirstOrDefault();
            string connectionStr = (string)connectionString;


        }

    }
 
}
```